# Why CORS in Express allowing all requests although I alllowed only GET in allowed method

Tags: node.js, api, express, cors

I am learning to implement API using Node.js, Express and MongoDB. I am on early learning phase. I have added cors package using `npm i cors` to the project. And I am using `cors` as middleware in my project as follows.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongojs = require("mongojs");

const { body, param, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const db = mongojs("travel", ["records"]);

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://a.com", "http://b.com"],
    methods: ["GET"],
    allowHeaders: ["Authorization", "Content-Type"],
  })
);

app.get("/api/records", cors(corsOptions), function (req, res) {
  db.records.find(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({
        meta: { total: data.length },
        data,
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post(
  "/api/records",
  [
    body("name").not().isEmpty(),
    body("from").not().isEmpty(),
    body("to").not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    db.records.insert(req.body, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500);
      }

      const _id = data._id;
      res.append("Location", "/api/records/" + _id);
      return res.status(201).json({
        meta: { _id },
        data,
      });
    });
  }
);

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log("Server running at port 8000...");
});
```

I only added `GET` request in the allowed methods. But when I try to `POST` new records, it is working properly. And moreover, I only added `"http://a.com", "http://b.com"` in the host list but all requests from localhost are working properly. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: What type of client are you doing the POST from?  Is it from a browser?  Or from some other http client.  CORS protections are ONLY implemented and enforced in a browser.  Also, is your request truly cross origin in that the request comes from a webpage that came from a different origin than you are using to access the POST request?

Comment: I am using Insomnia as client. "CORS protections are ONLY implemented and enforced in a browser". Noted. I guess it was not truly cross origin, since I was using localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and your subsequent comment, it sounds like there a couple things going on here:

1. CORS protections are only enforced by an actual browser engine.  If you're making the requests from a non-browser client, then there are no CORS limitations.
2. To trigger a CORs protection from a browser, you have to be making an actual cross origin call.  If everything is on `localhost`, then that won't be cross origin.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.